# Cookie expiration date

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am not a programmer. I am trying to use a cookie script that remembers the last drop down menu selection.

I found a script that works but it does only a session cookie. How do I add an expiration date to the cookie in this script?

```
<head>
  <script>        
    function SETcookie() {
      document.cookie = "Selected=" + document.getElementById('myList').selectedIndex;
    }

    function GETcookie() {
      if (document.cookie) {
        eval(document.cookie);
        document.getElementById('myList').selectedIndex = Selected;
      }
    }    
  </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="GETcookie()">
  <select id="myList" onChange="SETcookie()">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
function setCookie(c_name,c_value,exdays) {
   var exdate=new Date();
   exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
   document.cookie=encodeURIComponent(c_name) 
     + "=" + encodeURIComponent(c_value)
     + (!exdays ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
     ;
}
```

`c_name` is the name of the cookie

`c_value` is the cookie value

`exdays` is the number of days you want the cookie to expire after

> Source: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 9):

May be this will help

```
document.cookie = "coolName"+ "=" +"coolValue"+ ";" + "expires="+ new Date(new Date().getTime()+60*60*1000*24).toGMTString()+";path=/";
```

Comment: This will set expiry to exactly one day, which *might* be what you want... Mostly I either use session cookies/storage, or 'permanent' storage, by setting expiry to 10 years.

Answer (score 8):

Here's function which is 100% working and has no depreciated functions.

```
function setCookie(variable, value, expires_seconds) {
    var d = new Date();
    d = new Date(d.getTime() + 1000 * expires_seconds);
    document.cookie = variable + '=' + value + '; expires=' + d.toGMTString() + ';';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

try

```
var a = new Date();
a = new Date(a.getTime() +1000*60*60*24*365);
document.cookie = 'mycookie=somevalue; expires='+a.toGMTString()+';';
```

PS. The value 1000*60*60*24*365 = 1 Year

To Get the selected index try this GETcookie:

```
function GETcookie(){    
if (document.cookie){    
var a = document.cookie;
Selected = a.substring(a.search('Selected=')+9,a.search(';'));
alert("Selected = " + Selected);
document.getElementById('myList').selectedIndex=Selected;
}}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Maybe I put it in a wrong place. Can you show me how it supposed to be here http://jsfiddle.net/BrUmu/

Comment: Just set this in your SETcookie function. what do you get?

Comment: I did, the cookies stops working completely. See update here http://jsfiddle.net/BrUmu/1/

Answer (score 1):

;max-age=max-age-in-seconds (e.g., 60*60*24*365 or 31536000 for a year)
;expires=date-in-GMTString-format If neither expires nor max-age specified it will expire at the end of session.

```
document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; SameSite=None; Secure";
```

[know more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
function SETcookie(){  
  var validity_days = 7;
  var expires = validity_days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var expires_date = new Date( today.getTime() + (expires) );
  document.cookie="Selected="+document.getElementById('myList').selectedIndex + ";expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString() + ";";
}
```

Comment: "today" is not defined and your function is only for your own code, because it uses #myList DOM object. It's buggy and useless.

Comment: You are correct that 'today' is not defined here but "myList" was the id of the element from the question, it's not something they just made up.

Answer (score 0):

This is for setting the expiry date in terms of minutes(5 minutes here)

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {     
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + exdays * 60 * 1000);
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  
}

function getCookie(cname) {        
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
function checkCookie() {
  var user = getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
     //your code goes here
  } else {
     //your code goes here
    if (user != "" && user != null) {
      setCookie("username", user, 5);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for setting the expiry date in terms of days(5 days here)

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {     
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();

}

function getCookie(cname) {        
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
function checkCookie() {
  var user = getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
     //your code goes here
  } else {
     //your code goes here
    if (user != "" && user != null) {
      setCookie("username", user, 5);
    }
  }
}
```