# JavaScript Save Cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am following a tutorial for cookies and in the tutorial you enter your name, and you can refresh then display your name, so the name is actually saved as a cookie. However when I am trying this in a personal file, the cookie is not being saved if I refresh the page, I can only see the cookie once per session, so how do I save the cookie for as many **sessions** as I want?

I suppose you can't use **cookies** in a snippet, but if you can help, copy and paste this into a personal file.

```js
function WriteCookie() {
  customer = document.getElementById('customer');
  if (customer.innerHTML == "") {
    alert("Enter some value!");
    return;
  }
  cookievalue = escape(customer.innerHTML);
  document.cookie = "name=" + cookievalue;
  console.log("name=" + cookievalue);

  // expires
  var now = new Date();
  now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 1);

  document.cookie = "expires=" + now.toUTCString() + ";"
  // output = document.getElementById('output');
  // output.innerHTML = cookievalue;
}

function ReadCookie() {
  var allcookies = document.cookie;
  console.log("All Cookies : " + allcookies);

  // Get all the cookies pairs in an array
  cookiearray = allcookies.split(';');

  // Now take key value pair out of this array
  for (var i = 0; i < cookiearray.length; i++) {
    name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
    value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
    console.log("Key is : " + name + " and Value is : " + value);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="myform" action="">
    <!-- Enter name: <input type="text" name="customer"/> -->
    <h4>Enter Name:</h4>
    <h4 contenteditable="true" id="customer" style="background-color: #eee"></h4>
    <!-- <h4>Your Name is:</h4>
         <h4 id="output" style="width: 100%; height: 20px; background-color: #ddd;"></h4> -->
    <input type="button" value="Set Cookie" onclick="WriteCookie();" />
    <input type="button" value="Read Cookie" onclick="ReadCookie();" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any code setting expiration date time for cookie. To Set expiration time checke here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339406/cookie-expiration-date

Comment: @Knitesh — Cookies without expiry times are session cookies and expire when the browser is closed.

Comment: okay, @Knitesh I have added an expiration date, yet it still does not display the cookie.

Comment: @hannacreed — What URL (and most importantly URL scheme) are you using to test this page?

Comment: @Quentin I am using a file, so file:///, I suppose the cookies don't work in files? if not, how are you able to test a cookie??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are stored (in the browser) associated with a particular origin. Cookies are not supported on pages loaded with `file:` scheme URLs, as they lack hostnames.

Use HTTP (or HTTPS) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [localstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) instead.
it's much easier

or:  *also sessionStorage is suitable*