# Removing access_token in cookie before sending axios request

Tags: typescript, vue.js, cookies, axios

I've been trying to solve an issue in a Vue project on our request headers becoming to big for our servers to accept them, resulting in 413 error codes.

I'm using JWT bearer tokens, and I can see that the token is included in the request as `Authentication`-header, as well as in the cookie under `access_token`.

So far I've tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies removing the `access_token` cookie before all request, setting the `access_token=null` before all request, but to no avail.

I've tried with axios interceptors in hope removing the cookie before all requests, but I can't modify or remove the cookie via the interceptor.

Is there any way of modifying the cookie before requests, am I looking at the issue the wrong way, or am I better off increasing the allowed http header size limit?

Included is an example of the http-headers for a request

```
Host: *URL_HERE*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.c3FjSuQQwV3_jH1lVhqrLLtxK_X4Mt05rhduA9cgoTB9vzzJemm_fmQDqPfwLM9f_ddDBq896xrQVZvr2d9-fOBTq-k2ZJSLq4mswyZXsht3BeZmvsIPP6vXu_CitKqQUv9loaDMSYq8vtizIZNLzgSx8QmuETGafiNf2x3OxkUIj3KIUO08AVfCooDDrD8wYGSulhAbBudPQs7JEzJUJlY0jquHG4GzPGg3q72jIgxBmjw_27luGup9Fbzqe_E-w04B6d949MGgfggovqfASBd6Izaj-WwAQwgGTvMicMdtJikOU0x3h-XJonW86CbBdytqSvKZyaUKJFqLmuUXEQ
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: *URL_HERE*
Cookie: $netminers_$nmuid=921651885; $netminers_$nmvc=90; $netminers_$nmlv=174805; stg_returning_visitor=Thu%2C%2021%20Nov%202019%2013:32:12%20GMT; stg_last_interaction=Mon%2C%2009%20Dec%202019%2014:14:28%20GMT; _pk_id.f3057892-fff0-4957-8186-653c8557bbba.0499=da8a8ab6b8ca1108.1574342812.20.1575894064.1575894064.; cookieOptOut=y; cookieOptOut=y; S9SESSIONID=C5388EE9F19947E9B86E847E826020A8.sector9-es-s-s9s-t01; ERHVERVSFREMME_AUTH_COOKIE=7da2a729227d68d4da1d301906fcf21e0600632f; access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJDVlI6MTAxNTA4MTctUklEOmQ2ZTIzYzNjLTRjNWMtNDU5ZC05MGY5LTg0N2FiOTU5NjY4NyIsImlkZW50aXR5X2lkIjoiQ1ZSOjEwMTUwODE3LVJJRDpkNmUyM2MzYy00YzVjLTQ1OWQtOTBmOS04NDdhYjk1OTY2ODciLCJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJDVlI6MTAxNTA4MTctUklEOmQ2ZTIzYzNjLTRjNWMtNDU5ZC05MGY5LTg0N2FiOTU5NjY4NyIsInJpZCI6ImQ2ZTIzYzNjLTRjNWMtNDU5ZC05MGY5LTg0N2FiOTU5NjY4NyIsImVudGl0eV9pZCI6IkFBSUFCeDYtQW12NGYwUjJra3FXWEd0OWhObyIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfVklSS19NWU5ESUdIRUQiLCJST0xFX0JTMl9NWU5ESUdIRURfQURNSU5fRVJTVCIsIlJPTEVfU0FHU1NUWVJJTkdfRasdfsdaasdf19DTVNfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX0JSQU5DSEVLT0RFX0FETUlOIiwiUk9MRV9ESUFfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX0VSRl9VREJZREVSIiwiUk9MRV9ST19BRE1JTiIsIlJPTEVfKiIsIlJPTEVfVklSS19DTVNfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX1NBR1NTVFlSSU5HX0VSU1RfU0FHU0JFSEFORExFUiIsIlJPTEVfVElEX1RJTCIsIlJPTEVfTUxfUkVWSVNPUlRJTFNZTiIsIlJPTEVfRVJGX0FETUlOIiwiUk9MRV9TUk1fR1JPVVBfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX0NWUjpWUkJBVENIOkFETUlOSVNUUkFUSU9OIiwiUk9MRV9ESUFfUEFBX1ZFR05FX0FGIiwiUk9MRV9ST19TVVBQT1JURVIiLCJST0xFX0JNX0FETUlOIiwiUk9MRV9SRUdOU0tBQl9JTkRCRVJFVE5JTkdfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX0RJQURFTV9BRE1JTiIsIlJPTEVfUkVHTlNLQUJfSU5EQkVSRVROSU5HX01MIiwiUk9MRV9TSU1QRUxTQUdfRVJTVF9TVVBQT1JURVIiLCJST0xFX1JPX01BQV9TRV9GT1JUUk9MSUciLCJST0xFX1ZEX0VSU1RfU0FHU0JFSEFORExFUiIsIlJPTEVfRVJfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX1NTSV9TVVBQT1JURVIiLCJST0xFX1JPX1NBR1NCRUhBTkRMRVIiLCJST0xFX01LX0FETUlOIiwiUk9MRV9USVBfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX0JTMl9CTEFOS0VUX0VKRVIiLCJST0xFX0ZMSUlTX1NUQVRJU1RJSyIsIlJPTEVfU1JNX1JPTEVfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX0JSQU5DSEVLT0RFX1NBR1NCRUhBTkRMRVIiLCJST0xFX1RJRF9USUxfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX0JFU19BRE1JTiIsIlJPTEVfUk9fU0FHU0JFSEFORExFUl9VRFZJREVUIiwiUk9MRV9WSVJLUl9BRE1JTiIsIlJPTEVfQlMyX0JMQU5LRVRfQURNSU5JU1RSQVRPUiIsIlJPTEVfR01fUkVEQUtUT0VSX1JXIiwiUk9MRV9TQUdTU1RZUklOR19FUlNUX0FETUlOSVNUUkFUT1JfU09FR0VVRFRSWUsiXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiZXJodmVydnNmcmVtbWUtYWRtaW4iLCJ0b2tlbiI6bnVsbCwibG9nb3V0X3VybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vdGVzdC52aXJrc29taGVkc2d1aWRlbi5kay9zOS92aXJrc29taGVkc2d1aWRlbi9sb2dvdXQiLCJpZHAiOiJzYW1sLnRpcC5sb2dpbi10ZXN0LmRrIiwic2NvcGUiOlsicmVhZCIsIndyaXRlIl0sIm5hbWUiOiJFUlNUX0FkbWluaXN0cmF0b3IiLCJleHAiOjE1NzU5MjAwNzksImp0aSI6ImZhNDZmOTY2LTdlZjEtNDE5OC04NGZhLTViN2FkODdjYWY3NyIsImVtYWlsIjoiYmVza2VkZm9yZGVsZXJub25wcm9kQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImFzc3VyYW5jZV9sZXZlbCI6IjMiLCJjdnIiOiIxMDE1MDgxNyJ9.c3FjSuQQwV3_jH1lVhqrLLtxK_X4Mt05rhduA9cgoTB9vzzJemm_fmQDqPfwLM9f_ddDBq896xrQVZvr2d9-fOBTq-k2ZJSLq4mswyZXsht3BeZmvsIPP6vXu_CitKqQUv9loaDMSYq8vtizIZNLzgSx8QmuETGafiNf2x3OxkUIj3KIUO08AVfCooDDrD8wYGSulhAbBudPQs7JEzJUJlY0jquHG4GzPGg3q72jIgxBmjw_27luGup9Fbzqe_E-w04B6d949MGgfggovqfASBd6Izaj-WwAQwgGTvMicMdtJikOU0x3h-XJonW86CbBdytqSvKZyaUKJFqLmuUXEQ; SSESS73aa098e41c714a8d9c5ef6d225fe96a=PM08gbkgJw9mW3YJjt9reBBNaxfUJ9SAT7nIFf6Kr5o; SESSION=6885957a-00d1-48d5-ae4a-02411e19b59f; ERHVERVSFREMME_SYSTEM_COOKIE=b0819bed45df3fe05d3331740288ab271efa91db
Pragma: no-cache
```

My getters:

```
public get(restUrl: string, api?: API): AxiosPromise<any> {
    return axios.get(this.withApi(restUrl, api), this.requestConf());
  }
```

The requestconf method:

````
private requestConf(): AxiosRequestConfig {
    const token = authService.getJwt();
    const headers: any = {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    };
    if (!token) {
      console.warn('User is not logged in!');
    } else {
      headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return {
      headers
    };
  }```
````

Comment: Try set a expiration date for the cookie. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339406/cookie-expiration-date

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `config` object? it seems you can set the header there. Also you can set the header per application with the `create` instance config.
https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance

Comment: Yeah, I tried that as well, but it seems like something is setting the cookie in between creating the axios request and sending it